# Добавление сборок GAC в VS Code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2019

В директории C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL имеются свои сборки под net4.0. gacutil /l из обычного VS их все видит. При запуске стандартного консольного проекта (net5.0) в VS Code при добавлении этих сборок через using выдает ошибку, будто их нет. В project.json dependencies: также сборки не видит.

Comment: The global assembly cache (GAC) does not exist as a concept in .NET Core and .NET 5 and later versions. [Global assembly cache APIs are obsolete](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/global-assembly-cache-apis-obsolete) | https://stackoverflow.com/q/35538093/5045688

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov капец, я отстал от жизни! Спасибо за инфу.